# Save inner arrays as images from 2D outer array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a 4D array of shape `(7496, 32, 32, 1)` 7496 NumPy arrays arranged as 32x32 images in grayscale.
I would like to loop through this array of arrays and save them all as images, either jpg or bmp. Any method would do whether using PIL, OpenCV or any other APIs or libraries, thank you all in advance!

I have managed to do one single image for practice I just need to know how to do it at scale in one go.

```
for t in range(0, 1):
    plt.imshow(normal_imgs[t], cmap = 'gray')
    plt.show()
    
    cv2.imwrite(CWD + '/image_before.bmp', normal_imgs[t])
```

```
img_b3 = cv2.imread('image_before.bmp', 0)
equ3 = cv2.equalizeHist(img_b3)
# res = np.hstack((img_b,equ))
img_a3 = cv2.imwrite('image_after.bmp', equ3)
img_a_out3 = cv2.imread('image_after.bmp', 0)
```

The file names can be something simple like `normal_train_1, normal_train_2` etc

Comment: If an answer helped you, please accept it, If not, please explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
import os


for t in range(0, normal_imgs.shape[0]):
    original = normal_imgs[t]
    equalized = cv2.equalizeHist(original )
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(CWD, 'image_after.bmp'), equalized)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use PIL to save images:
this will save your images as img1.jpg img2.jpg etc. you should change the path variable to get where to save and what file name to save as.
note that "L" mode only accept an 8-bit uint array as input, so it is important to cast array with `astype(np.uint8)`

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


# imgs = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255,size=(20, 32, 32, 1))
imgs = imgs.reshape((20, 32, 32)).astype(np.uint8)
path = "./imgs/img{:d}.jpg"


for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    print(img.shape)
    Image.fromarray(img, mode="L").save(path.format(i))
```